# EventLogQuery time format expected?

Tags: .net

I'm trying to use the EventLogQuery class to query the eventlog.  I followed the example shown on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671200%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Y0.

I've searched Google a ton but can't find any queries with the @SystemTime not hard-coded in there.

Does anyone know the DateTime format I need to use for this?  Everything I've tried so far has returned "Invalid Query" exceptions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EventLogQuery uses an XML format to query the event log.
You can find the schema for the query XML [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385760.aspx).

The text of the [Select element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385766.aspx) is an XPath expression evaluated against the XML serialization of events.

You can find the schema for the event XML [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385201.aspx).

The [TimeCreated element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385211.aspx) has an attribute SystemTime of type [dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime), so the format of this (in your query XML) is whatever an XPath processor can parse as a valid dateTime (see [3.2.7.1. **Lexical representation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-lexical-representation) for the specifics).

For example you can try a query like this:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime = '2011-12-20T00:42:53.000000000Z']]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Which parses and returns a value if you happen to have an event created exactly at the given date and time.

Also [dateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231313.aspx) is an extension function to the Filter XPath protocol, which takes one or two arguments of [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230375.aspx) type and returns a number, so just use a number in expression with this function (just like in your example).

---

P.S. You can use the Windows Event Viewer (`%windir%\system32\eventvwr.msc`) to enter and quickly evaluate event query XML by [creating Custom Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709635.aspx) (Windows Vista, 7 and 2008 only):

[image]

Comment: thanks great post. I would just like to add here is that the date time format accepted here is dtObj.ToString("O"). dtObj is your starting datetime object.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another C# for initializing an EventLogQuery object that will load event entires for a specific date range

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
var endTime = DateTime.Now;

var query = string.Format("*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '{0}']]] and *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime <= '{1}']]]",
    startTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"),
    endTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));

var elq = new EventLogQuery("Applicaton", PathType.LogName, query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a C# example for initializing an EventLogQuery object that will only load event entries from the last day.

```
var yesterday = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);

var yesterdayDtFormatStr = yesterday.ToString(
   "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff00K", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);

var query = string.Format(
   "*[System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime >='{0}']", 
   yesterdayDtFormatStr
);

var elq = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, query);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Event XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399427.aspx)

There is an example here of the XML with a string version of the expected date format.

```
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2006-02-28T21:51:44.754Z" />
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.  However, could you please give me an example of what the format string would look like for this?

Comment: @user1106686 I have edited my answer to include the line from the example with a string datetime.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Failed Login IP List in Last 2 Hour.  EventID=4625 AND CreatedDate >= Last 2 Hour**

```
var AfterTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-120);

string queryString =
                    "<QueryList>" +
                    "  <Query Id='0' Path='Security'>" +
                    $"    <Select Path='Security'>*[System[(EventID=4625) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='{AfterTime.ToString("o")}']]]</Select>" +
                    "  </Query>" +
                    "</QueryList>";  

var reader = new EventLogReader(new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, queryString));

for (EventRecord eventDetail = reader.ReadEvent(); eventDetail != null; eventDetail = reader.ReadEvent())
{
    if (eventDetail.Id == 4625 && eventDetail.TimeCreated >= AfterTime)// Extra security, check again
    {
                    IPlist.Add(eventDetail.Properties[eventDetail.Properties.Count - 2].Value.ToString()); // Get IP Adress, Last Second Element Has IP Adress
    }

}

var AttackerIP = IPlist.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```