# Filtering EventLogs with C# by Date and Provider Name

Tags: c#, eventlog-source

I want to filter my Events Logs on Windows with C#. 
I'm using this code bellow, that works fine only if I have one condition in query.

When I try to input more that one condition, I get the error:

> The specified query is invalid

```
string FormattedDateTime = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}T{3}:{4}:{5}.000000000Z",
                                          DateTime.Now.Year,
                                          DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("D2"),
                                          DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Day.ToString("D2"),
                                          DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("D2"),
                                          DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("D2"),
                                          DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("D2"));

query = String.Format("*[System/Provider/@Name=\"{0}\" and TimeCreated/@SystemTime&gt;='{1}']", "MyApplication", FormattedDateTime);

var QueryResult = new EventLogQuery(LogSource, PathType.LogName, query);
```

So, the error occurrs in this line:

```
var Reader = new System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader(QueryResult);
```

I've tried any differents combinations for this query, but without success.

Comment: are you missing a space on either side of the '>=' in the second condition? `TimeCreated/@SystemTime &gt;= '{1}`

Comment: It made no difference. The error continues ...

Comment: Try replacing &gt; with actual > symbol

Comment: Also I believe your formatting string can be replaced with DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.000000000Z") - which is safer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EventLogQuery time format expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567368/eventlogquery-time-format-expected)